# JOOQ @Transactional on multiple repository

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, transactions, jooq

Situation:

I have scheduled task with a 15 min long run. It regenerates 2 tables. I'd like to do it in ONE transaction, but with the @Transational the repo calls have 2 different transactions, for the lot of repo calls.

It's a spring boot 2 project with postgres.

Is it possible the repos has different connections?

(I removed and simplified some DI.)

Code sample:

```
@Scheduled(...)
public class ScheduledTaskRunner
{
    @Transactional
    public void run()
    {
        aService.parseXML();
        bService.parseCSV();
    }
}

@Service
public class AService
{
    public function parseXML()
    {
         for (Node node : parserMethodSomewhere())
         {
            aRepository.save(node.getDataA(), node.getDataB());
         }
    }
}

@Service
public class BService
{
    public function parseCSV()
    {
         for (Node node : parserMethodSomewhere())
         {
            bRepository.save(node.getDataA(), node.getDataB());
         }
    }
}

@Service
public class ConnectionService
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private Connection connection = null;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        if (null == connection)
        {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        }

        return connection;
    }
}

@Service
public class JooqService
{
    @Autowired
    private Connection connection;
    private DSLContext dslContext = null;

    public DSLContext createQueryBuilder()
    {
        if (null == dslContext)
        {
           this.dslContext = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
        }

        return dslContext;
    }
}

@Repository
public abstract class AbstractRepository
{
    @Autowired
    private JooqService jooqService;

    DSLContext createQueryBuilder()
    {
        return jooqService.createQueryBuilder();
    }
}

public function ARepository extends AbstractRepository
{
    public function save(int a, int b)
    {
        createQueryBuilder().insertInto(table, table.a, table.b).values(a, b).execute();
    }
}

public function BRepository extends AbstractRepository
{
    public function save(int a, int b)
    {
        createQueryBuilder().insertInto(table, table.a, table.b).values(a, b).execute();
    }
}
```

=============================================
WORKAROUND - SOLUTION:

```
@Scheduled(...)
public class ScheduledTaskRunner
{
    // @Transactional
    public void run()
    {
        jooqService.createQueryBuilder().transaction(
            (configuration) ->
            {
                aService.parseXML();
                bService.parseCSV();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but you really shouldn't have a `static DSLContext` reference in a `Service`, especially since your `DSLContext` references an individual `Connection`. Your design means that any `JooqService` implementation will use the same JDBC connection.

I also doubt you should cache your JDBC `Connection` as well. Ideally, your `DSLContext` wraps the `DataSource` directly. That's the best way to have jOOQ plug into your configured transaction management by properly acquiring a `Connection` from the data source, and releasing it again after use by calling `Connection.close()` for you.

Comment: The static was just my last try. Now I add cache to the getter in the ConnectionService and a logger to the getter. I have only one call on it: HikariProxyConnection@2021993849 returns. It really looks like I have only one connection and I still have the same problem.

Comment: There is a third param call settings, on the DSL.using(). Now I see a default conf: 
DefaultConfiguration [
 connected=true,
 transactional=false,
 dialect=POSTGRES,
 data={},
 settings=...

Comment: Should I add somewhere a transactionProvider?

Comment: @KrizsánBalazs: There's a lot of magic going on when using Spring / Annotation based configurations. You probably no longer work with the code that you've posted, so I'm likely barking up the wrong tree (e.g. the static reference). Normally, you should really just pass a `DataSource` to jOOQ, and things will work. A transaction provider might be needed only if you use the jOOQ transaction API, which you don't. jOOQ is completely oblivious of Spring's transactions this way, which means that you have more of a Spring problem than a jOOQ problem.

Comment: @KrizsánBalazs: Perhaps it's best to start over again, and try to configure things afresh? Perhaps you could base your configuration on one of the Spring based jOOQ examples? https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples

Comment: You are right, the code was a little bit changed (no more static, and connection is cached too), but now I solved it with using jooqService.createQueryBuilder().transaction((configuration) ->{ service calls }) instead of the annotation. It's fine now, I'll investigate the difference, but it's a good temporary solution.